# Export C functions for LabView with c++builder

Tags: c++builder, dllexport, labview, teststand

I have a DLL that I have ported from VC2008 to C++ Builder XE2.  The DLL is used in LabVIEW's TestStand.

TestStand, when importing the VC2008 DLL, can see the function names and their arguments. When using the C++ Builder DLL, all its sees are the function names and not the arguments.  All exports are C functions and use `extern "C" declspec( dllexport )`.

Is there a way to get the exports correct?

I have read that adding a TLB file will do the job, if this is true, how do I create a TLB that exports only C functions?

Comment: Do you actually need TestStand to see what the calling parameters are?  If you can see the function names, and you have the source code for the DLL... can you not just define which parameters need to be passed in?  I haven't used TestStand in forever, but you can do this in LabVIEW.

Comment: I am passing the DLL to testers that may not know how to do this properly.  Turns out test stand will read a .c/.cpp file and figure out the parameters that way.  Problem solved.

Comment: How about just the header file?  Just in case you didn't want all of your code to be distributed?

Comment: It has to be a .c or .cpp file, so I made a dummy source file from the header file and added `{}` in place of the `;`.  I then wrapped it up in `#if 0` so it would not compile.  TestStand still reads it, works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestStand can read a .c/.cpp file and derive parameters from that file.  You still load the DLL and select the function you want to call. You then 'verify' the parameters and select the .c/.cpp file in the dialog.  TestStand will find the function with the same name and insert the parameters itself.

The function must be very specific, I had to create a dummy .c file that contained the prototypes as TestStand could not handle the #defines for dllexport and dllimport.  It likes a very specific format.  For the function:

```
TESTAPI bool StartTest( long inNumber ) {}
```

where `TESTAPI`is either `extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )` or `extern "C" __declspec( dllimport` I had to write the line below in my dummy file:

```
bool __declspec( dllexport ) StartTest( long inNumber ) {}
```

That does it.

Answer (score 1):

DLL function parameters cannot be determined from exports alone, unless they are being decorated by the calling convention (which is unusual to do in a DLL).  If a TLB (aka a Type Library) solves the problem, then the VC2008 DLL is likely an In-Process ActiveX/COM object rather than a flat C DLL.  If so, then in C+Builder you can use the IDE wizards on the "File | New" menu to create an "ActiveX Library" project, then a "COM Object" to add to the library.  Then you will have a TLB that you can define your object with, and the IDE will generate stub code that you can fill in with your object's implementation.

If that is not what LabViews is expecting, then I suggest you contact them and ask. If all it needs is a TLB with flat C functions (which is very unusual, because TLB's are object-oriented), then you can omit the "COM Object" portion and just create an "ActiveX Library" project to get a bare-bones TLB, then add your definitions to it as needed, an then add your exports to the project.

Comment: The VS2008 DLL is a flat C DLL, I know, I wrote it myself.  And yet it contains the names and arguments of all exported functions.  Hmmm, I do notice that I only use __declspec( dllexport ) on the functions in VS2008, but have to use extern "C' in C++ Builder.  That would make a difference as the functions for a C++ DLL will have decoration.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370052H-01/tsref/infotopics/exporting_in_net/):

> Avoid using the extern "C" syntax to export symbols. The extern "C" syntax prevents the C/C++ DLL Adapter from obtaining type information for function and method parameters."

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game, but your problem may be that C++ Builder is decorating the exported function with a leading underscore. The `TLIB` command line utility should help prove this (assuming tlib still ships with C++Builder)

```
TLIB mydll.lib, mydll.lst
```

Look at the resulting lst file and see if it contains `StartTest` or `_StartTest`. LabView is probably expecting to find a function without the underscore.

You can add a DEF file to your C++Builder project that will suppress the leading underscore. Try this:

1. Use the __cdecl calling convention instead of __stdcall.
2. Export plain "C" functions. No C++ classes or member functions.
3. Make sure you have an extern "C" {} around your function prototypes.
4. Create a DEF file that aliases the exported functions to a Microsoft
   compatible name. Alias the names so they don't contain a leading
   underscore. The DEF file will look like this:

   EXPORTS
      ; MSVC name    = C++Builder name
        StartTest    = _StartTest
        Foo          = _Foo
        Bar          = _Bar

5- Add the DEF file to your BCB DLL project and rebuild it.

Check out these ancient articles for more details:
http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0012/Using_Visual_C_DLLs_with_CBuilder.htm

The reverse article (creating C++Builder DLLs that get called from VC++ created applications) is buried in this archive:

http://www.frasersoft.net/program/bcbdev.zip : /articles/bcbdll.htm. It describes the DEF file trick in more detail, plus some other options.

Note that my answer is based on the way thing were in 1998 or so. They may have changed since then. If they have, then the C++Builder command line tools impdef, tlib, tdump, plus the Microsoft equivalents of those tools, should be able to show you exactly what is in your DLL vs the MSVC one.

H^2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use ActiveX object: you can create an automation object in C++Builder and in Labview / TestStand you can import this object. If you use automation, in Lavbiew you will have the correct parameter definition. Make sure you are using a set of compatible type variables with Labview / TestStand.
For example, this fragment of code is the implementation of an array passed from Labview to C++:

```
STDMETHODIMP TCanLibraryImpl::DataDownload(VARIANT Data, long* RV)
{
   _precondition_cmodule();   
   *RV = 0;
   TSafeArrayLong1 mySafeArray(Data.parray);
   int dLen =mySafeArray.BoundsLength[0];
   ...
}
```

In Labview you will pass to this function an array of I64